# Implementation of count(*) in Graphene / Mongo

Tags: mongodb, flask, mongoengine, graphene-python

Good afternoon,

How may I implement a count of items back of MongoDB request and make it available through GraphQl request ? I am currently using MongoDB <=> MongoEngine <=> graphene <=> Flask .

Any help will be welcomed .

Thanks

B.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of time, reading forums and Internet pages, I am now able to retrieve the total count of entity send back from MongoDB.

Here is the Models.py

```
from mongoengine import Document
from mongoengine.fields import StringField
class User(Document):
    meta = {'collection': 'user'}
    first_name = StringField(required=True)
    last_name = StringField(required=True)
```

Here is the Schema.py

```
from graphene_mongo import MongoengineObjectType,MongoengineConnectionField
import graphene
from graphene.relay import Node
from Models import User as UserModel
from mongoengine import connect
from flask import Flask
from flask_graphql import GraphQLView

connect(db="graphene-mongo-example",host="127.0.0.1:27017",alias="default")


class Connection(graphene.Connection):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    total_count = graphene.Int()

    def resolve_total_count(self, info):
        return len(self.edges)

class User(MongoengineObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        interfaces=(Node,)
        filter_fields = {'first_name': {'startswith', 'contains'}, 'last_name': [""]}
        connection_class = Connection

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):

    Node=Node.Field()
    all_users = MongoengineConnectionField(User)


schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.add_url_rule(
    "/graphql", view_func=GraphQLView.as_view("graphql", schema=schema, graphiql=True,types=[User])
  )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

To run this example :

```
python Schema.py
```